# Laravel eloquent orderby two fields with the same name

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, sql-order-by

I have two tables "Companies" and "Properties"
Have a relationship defined in Property class: return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
I run this eloquent query to get all properties with companies

```
$properties=Property::with('company')->orderBy('name')->get();
```

What i can't figure out is how do i orderBy Company.name first and then orderBy property.name? If I do this: orderBy('company.name') I will get an error.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`join()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#joins) as:

```
$properties = Property::join('companies', 'properties.company_id', '=', 'companies.id')
                      ->orderBy('companies.name')
                      ->orderBy('properties.name')
                      ->select('properties.*')
                      ->with('company')
                      ->get();
```

Comment: Worked great. I did try join(), but I was doing that after with() function, that did not work for me.